# Cannot add reference to my WCF service although the service found

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I followed this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx
And after host my service and the service is running i created console application project, add service reference the the service found.
after that i try to test the client so i wrote `ServiceReference1` (ServiceReference1 is my service references) to create service instance and after this i only can see `IService1` and not my service name which is `Service1`.

I did something wrong ?

Comment: can you paste your service code? Also It should have created a ServiceClient1 class too that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, ServiceClient1 was created and that was my problem.

Comment: I think @AdityaPatil Should make a formal answer and you OP vote it as the answer in this case instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have created a ServiceClient1 class too that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

IService1 is the contract between the service and clients, which is published. Service1 is the implementation of IService1, and clients need not and should not have knowledge of it. Through naming convention only, when VS IDE or SvcUtil.exe generates the proxy class for IService1 (NOT Service1), the proxy class is by default named as Service1Client.

For example, in your service side, you have IService1 and class MyInternalImp implementing the interface, the client proxy class generated will be Servce1Client, NOT MyInternalImpClient, since the WSDL won't care about the implementation details, but the interface only.

You might have read some codes that have DataContractAttribute decorating a class rather than an interface, that's malpractice, even though .NET will generate an interface at runtime, on the behalf of publishing the interface/WSDL.

So you are referencing a service called IService1, while Service1 is not the service, but the implementation of the service side, which should not be the concern of the clients.